# How to fetch json array inside array in android listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm having json format as below , How do i fetch it into listview in android, While i'm trying to do,  following error rises. I,m having multiple starting array square brackets.

```
                 org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":"30","title":"Android Design Engineer","postedDate":"2016-11-19","jobtype":"Contract","location":"Alabama","description":"Basic knowladge in android can give him so many advantages to develop and learna android in an openly sourced android developer in India and hes an outsourcer of the manditory field in and entire world","experience":"2 to 6 yrs","salary":" Upto $50"}] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

and the following my java code is, here i call jsosarray and split it into objects.

```
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.3.2/utyessjobsi/jobdetail");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String recode = String.valueOf(code);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
             json_result = bufferedReader.readLine();

            try {
                if (code == 200) {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_result);
                    int length = jsonArray.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String jobname = c.getString(TAG_JOBTITLE);
                        String description = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                        String jobtype = c.getString(TAG_JOBTYPE);
                        String salary = c.getString(TAG_SALARY);
                        String postedon = c.getString(TAG_POSTEDDATE);
                        String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                        String exp = c.getString(TAG_EXPE);


                        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        result.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        result.put(TAG_JOBTITLE, jobname);
                        result.put(TAG_DESC, description);
                        result.put(TAG_JOBTYPE, jobtype);
                        result.put(TAG_SALARY, salary);
                        result.put(TAG_POSTEDDATE,postedon);
                        result.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                        result.put(TAG_EXPE, exp);


                            resultList.add(result);

                    }
                } else {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_result);
                    status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                    msg = jsonObj.getString("msg");
                }
                return recode;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Json erroe", e.toString());
                return e.toString();
```

My Json array

```
 [
  [
   {
      "id": "30",
     "title": "Android Design Engineer",
      "description": "Basic knowladge in android can give him so many  advantages to develop and learna android in an openly sourced android developer in India and hes an outsourcer of the manditory field in and entire world",
  "jobtype": "Contract",
  "salary": " Upto $50",
  "postedDate": "2016-11-19",
  "location": "Alabama",
  "experience": "2 to 6 yrs"
     }
   ],
    [
     {
       "id": "24",
      "title": "Android Application Developer",
        "description": "Android Application Developer is the major Development Technique that is used in this damn World.",
    "jobtype": "Contract",
  "salary": " Upto $50",
  "postedDate": "2016-11-16",
  "location": "North Carolina",
  "experience": "6 to 10 yrs"
      }
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: It's a correct Json value from your server ?

Comment: please look into my updated question

Comment: This JSON data design is not good for mobile consume services.It's create memory issues for low end devices

Comment: Your JSON data design is not good but for this same you can check readyandroid answer for parsing json

Answer (score 1):

Check below parsing logic as per your JSON:

```
try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.3.2/utyessjobsi/jobdetail");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                int code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                String recode = String.valueOf(code);
                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                json_result = bufferedReader.readLine();

                try {
                    if (code == 200) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_result);
                        if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONArray jsonChildArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                                if (jsonChildArray != null && jsonChildArray.length() > 0) {
                                    JSONObject c = jsonChildArray.getJSONObject(0);

                                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                                    String jobname = c.getString(TAG_JOBTITLE);
                                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                                    String jobtype = c.getString(TAG_JOBTYPE);
                                    String salary = c.getString(TAG_SALARY);
                                    String postedon = c.getString(TAG_POSTEDDATE);
                                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                                    String exp = c.getString(TAG_EXPE);


                                    HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    result.put(TAG_ID, id);
                                    result.put(TAG_JOBTITLE, jobname);
                                    result.put(TAG_DESC, description);
                                    result.put(TAG_JOBTYPE, jobtype);
                                    result.put(TAG_SALARY, salary);
                                    result.put(TAG_POSTEDDATE, postedon);
                                    result.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                                    result.put(TAG_EXPE, exp);


                                    resultList.add(result);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_result);
                        status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                        msg = jsonObj.getString("msg");
                    }
                    return recode;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Json erroe", e.toString());
                    return e.toString();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("erroe", e.toString());
                return e.toString();
            }
```

Comment: Here main logic behind parsing is from Main JSONArray you have to loop and get child JSONArray and every child JSONArray is having only one JSONObject. This JSONObject you have to use for your listview item, so add it to the arraylist.

Comment: Super answer by @Ready Android, Thank you for helping my guy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes .There is an error.Your JSON Data has An array inside array and you are trying to assign internal array as object.

First convert outer array JsonArray jsonArray1;

Iterate through this array. i=0 -> jsonArray1.length; and create another

JsonArray jsonArray2 = jsonArray1[i];

And finally iterate through jsonArray2: j=0 -> jsonArray2.length()

and create a JsonObject json = jsonArray2[j];

I hope you understood. This is psuedocode. If you want code, tell me.I can write it.